# QT5.9.1でwebviewのビルド

Tags: qt5

QT5.9.1のサンプルのwebiviewを試したいのですが

webview.proをビルドすると何も表示されずに終了。
minibrowser.proをビルドすると

Unknow module(s) in QT: webview

と表示されビルドできず。
サンプルを試せず困っています。
どうすれば、このサンプルを動かすことができますか？

Comment: qmakeに失敗している感じに見えます。ビルド環境は何でしょうか?

Comment: プロジェクトを開く時に、Configure ProjectでDesktop Qt 5.9.1 MinGW 32bitにしてます。

Answer (score 1):

`Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MinGW 32bit`ということなので、Windows版と予想します。
Windows版の場合、MinGW版ではWebViewはサポートされていないと思います。(ベースになるQtWebEngineがサポートされていないため)
そのため、質問のエラーが発生していると思います。

＃エラーメッセージは、qmake実行時に`minibrowser.pro`に記載されているモジュール`webview`が見つからない、という意味です。

WindowsだとQt MSVC2013かMSVC2015版であればコンパイル、実行できると思います。
(そのためには、少なくともVisual Studio Communityを導入する必要があります)

Comment: うまくいきました。Visual Studio Community 2017を C++によるデスクトップ開発 にチェックをつけてインストール後、QT5.9.1をフルチェックでインストール、webview.pro を Desktop QT 5.9.1 MSVC2017 64bit で開いてビルド、実行できました。ありがとうございました！